# Using Javascript/JQuery to Filter XML results

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

Ok, I am doing my nut trying to figure this out...

I have a page that pulls up a bunch of XML data and it is working fine.

I then decided to add a search box on this and other pages that will make this page only show the results of my search.

I know that the page is receiving the form data and that it is being correctly stored in variables.

I want to use those variables to then filter the results of my xml file.

What I have currently is;

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ResidentialProperty");
mySearch = location.search.substr(1).split("&")
function getFromSearch() {
  var x = 0
  mySearch = location.search.substr(1).split("&")
  for (x=0;x<=mySearch.length;x++) {
    eval("document.forms.myNewForm."+mySearch[x])
  }
}
document.write(mySearch);
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) { 
  var item = x[i];
  document.write("<div class='property'><div class='list_name'>");
  if(item !== undefined) {
      var itemElements = item.getElementsByTagName("StreetNumber");
      if(itemElements.length > 0) {
          if(itemElements[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
              document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("StreetNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+' ');
          }
      }
  }
  if(item !== undefined) {
      var itemElements = item.getElementsByTagName("StreetDirPrefix");
      if(itemElements.length > 0) {
          if(itemElements[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
              document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("StreetDirPrefix")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+' ');
          }
      }
  }
```

etc.

This is all working but every time I try to filter it just stops all results returning.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be worth using a library like jQuery for this problem.

e.g. (taking a stab at the code without any testing)

```
var xml = $(xmlDoc);
var properties = xml.find('ResidentialProperty');

mySearch = location.search.substr(1).split("&");

var results = properties.filter(function() {
    return $(this).val().substr(0, mysearch.length) === mySearch;
}); 

console.log(results);
```

Reference

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/02/jquery-parse-json-xml-html.html

https://api.jquery.com/find/

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Thank you Sharn. I am trying to get it working with your help. No luck so far but I will keep plugging away.